# App Preview recording with iOS Simulator cause NSPOSIXErrorDomain with code 22 ERROR

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I was trying to capture video for app Preview from ios simulator with implementing command in terminal.

but when i try to use the command bellow

`xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo appPreview.mp4`

the terminal gives me the error:

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Selected interface does not support video recording.
Invalid argument
```

can someone explain what is the problem here and how to resolve this problem?

I am using XCODE Version 11.0 beta 5 (11M382q)

and running ios simulator Xs Max

[image]

Comment: Unrelated (maybe) to the issue but never use outdated betas. Always stay current.

Answer (score 8):

[It is a known issue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes). `"Video recording of the iOS 13, tvOS 13, and watchOS 6 simulator through xcrun simctl io <UDID> recordVideo returns an error instead of recording video. (50625716)"`

Unrelated, but the Xcode 11 GM is out - beta 5 is outdated.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. so are you saying all i have to do is to update the xcode?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it's a bug with Xcode 11 at the moment, so updating it (as of today) still won't fix it. I was just saying that you're not on the latest beta/GM anyway.

Comment: okay thanks.. please let me know if you find any solution cause i am trying to create appPreview with  Quicktime player but the app store connect wont let me to do so because of resolution issue..

Comment: @MD.SazidHasanDip I guess the most obvious workaround, for now, would be to use Xcode 10 - but it depends if you need iOS 13/Swift UI etc. The only other option really is to wait for Apple to fix it in Xcode 11.

Comment: i have tried the latest Xcode 11 GM seed . because i was thinking to play with SwiftUI but could not solve the main issue so i downloaded the latest stable xcode 10.3 and it works fine..

Comment: This is listed as fixed in the release notes for Xcode 11.2 Beta.  Tried this with Catalina Version 10.15 Beta (19A582a) and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in Xcode 11.2; installing that version of Xcode will upgrade your CoreSimulator which also fixes Xcode 11.0 and 11.1.

Comment: okay i will test it out since i am using xcode 10.3.. should i go for the upgrade now or should i wait for apple's notification to upgrade the xcode?

Comment: updated to 11.2.1 and still hitting the above error

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [chumps52](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57947708/923288), this is a known issue. You can however use Xcode 11 to record video of the iOS 12 Simulators (and below). So unless you have specific iOS 13 things to show in your video, use for example a 12.2 simulator to record.

Comment: i did tried that too.. unfortunately it did not work for me with xcode 11 so i switched to the latest stable version of xcode 10..

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was actually that i'd passed an invalid output filename
eg.

`xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo invalid-folder/appPreview.mp4`

where `invalid-folder` didn't exist. The resultant output was:

```sh
Couldn't create an asset writer for writing video frames: allocationErrorError starting video recorder: simctl.SimulatorError.allocationError.
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=simctl.SimulatorError, code=2):
We could not allocate necessary AV objects to perform the recording.
```